# how to show large image onclick row flutter?

Tags: flutter, image

I have image in a row from a function like this:

```html
_buildSetMenuItemImage() {
    final url = Outlet().baseUrl +
        "/images/${widget.menuItem.imageUrl}";
    return ClipRRect(
      child: Image.network(
        url,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
      ),
    );
  }
```

when click on image in row (not whole row), it must show large image like this :
[image: image in row]

[image: large image after click small image]

How to repair the function code so it will show large image when clicked?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a dialog to show image in full screen

```
class CustomDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  String imageUrl;
    CustomDialog({required this.imageUrl});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
    child:Container(
      color:Colors.black,
      
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
      
         Padding(
           padding:EdgeInsets.only(top:120,bottom:120),
         child: Image.network(
                  imageUrl,
                  width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  fit:BoxFit.fitWidth
                ),
         ),
              Positioned(
            right:60,
            top:60,
            
          child:IconButton(
            
          icon:Icon(Icons.close,size:70,color:Colors.red),onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
          })
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

and can use it like below

```
 showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return CustomDialog(imageUrl:"https://picsum.photos/200/300");
              },
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
_buildSetMenuItemImage() {
    final url = Outlet().baseUrl +
        "/images/${widget.menuItem.imageUrl}";
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        showDialog(...); // show a dialog like Nikhil explained
      },
      child: ClipRRect(
        child: Image.network(
          url,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Addition to Nikhil Biju's code you can modify your code like this. This modify gains an on click event to your image especially.